# How do you do worldbuilding for many worlds in a collection of short stories when you have multiple worlds, and multiple alternate histories?

Tags: short-story, world-building

How do you do worldbuilding for many worlds in a collection of short stories when you have multiple worlds, and multiple alternate histories?

Say you're writing a collection of short stories, and sometimes a story takes place within world X, but there are 20 different timelines and at least a dozen of worlds that are similar, but different. How do you deal with the fact that some of these short stories seem to contradict the worldbuilding you did for other short stories without telling your readers that they're taking place in an alternate world or a different universe?

I am wondering if you should not care about it at all and somehow hope that your readers somehow figure it out by themselves, instead of telling them exactly what they need to know.